Android Studio wrongly highlights unresolved reference to a resource in a Kotlin Multiplatform project
Kotlin multiplatform gradle project, Android namespace, e.g. com.foo.android is different from actual code packages directory structure, say, com.bar.android in the Android module, and different from application ID, for example, com.pub.android.
"import com.foo.android.R" is OK, but  resource reference like R.string.some_text_resource is highlighted as error "Unresolved reference" in part of some_text_resource. At the same time the app builds and runs successfully. Appears that Android Studio wrongly reports "Unresolved reference" for all the resource references in the projects, strings, drawables, etc. How to fix the inspection?
Tried all the suggestiond like invalidate caches, restart project, reindex, remove all build directories, .idea folder and reimport project. Does not help
